# MemoryError while loading huge initial data

Tags: database, django, memory, data-migration

I have the initial data from my old database which takes around 6GB. I could "dumpdata" my old database without any problem. But when I attempted to restore them to the new database, I got the `MemoryError`:

```
    python manage.py loaddata fixtures/initial_data.json
    MemoryError: Problem installing fixture 'fixtures/initial_data.json':
```

Is there any way to make `loaddata` work with chunks or is it possible to load that big file?

Comment: How many tables does the fixture contain? If more than one, you could split one table per file.

Comment: there are several tables but only one of them is that huge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For large database use backup tools for dumping database data instead "django dumpdata".
To load database data use restore tools instead "django loaddata".

Comment: I think that's the only one way. The problem is that one database is Sql Server and the other is Postgres, it will be hard to copy foreign keys.

Comment: @user2211623: Does the standard technique of copying the data without FK constraints, and then re-imposing the constraints at the end, not work?

Comment: @user2211623: Article [Microsoft SQL Server to PostgreSQL Migration by Ian Harding](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server_to_PostgreSQL_Migration_by_Ian_Harding)

Comment: Thank you. I think I will do it in that way. I also couldn't find anything about this MemoryError anywhere. So, that.

Answer (score 8):

I've wrote this script, which is a fork of django's dumpdata, but dumps data in chunks to avoid MemoryError. And then load these chunks one by one.

Script is available at https://github.com/fastinetserver/django-dumpdata-chunks

Example usage:

1) Dump data into many files:

```
mkdir some-folder

./manage.py dumpdata_chunks your-app-name
--output-folder=./some-folder --max-records-per-chunk=100000
```

2) Load data from the folder:

```
find ./some-folder | egrep -o "([0-9]+_[0-9]+)" | xargs ./manage.py loaddata
```

PS. I used it to move data from Postgresql to MySQL.

Comment: Why would you move from Postgresql to MySQL?

Comment: As always: client's request :) Reasons: client want to integrate data with some php framework that supports only mysql.